# Retrieving Datastore Object With Key

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

Using examples from the GAE documentation I have successfully put and object to the datastore as I can view it in the admin console.  Retrieving has been difficult, here is my code.

```
import webapp2
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

user_key = ndb.Key('Info_model', 'Bill')

class Info_model(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    active = ndb.BooleanProperty()

class Create_entity(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    user1 = Info_model(username = 'Bill', 
                       phone = 1231231234, 
                       active = False)
    user1.put()
    self.response.write('<!doctype html><html><body>Entity created.<pre>')
    self.response.write('</pre></body></html>')

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    #get object from datastore using example from GAE Documentation.
    user_key = ndb.Key('Info_model', 'Bill')
    user1 = user_key.get()

    self.response.write(user1.username)
    self.response.write(user1.phone)
    self.response.write(user1.active)
    self.response.write('</body></html>')
application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
('/', MainPage),
('/create', Create_entity)
], debug=True)
```

From [datastore documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#retrieving_entities):

It says:
**Retrieving Entities from Keys**
Given an entity's key, you can retrieve the entity from the Datastore:

```
sandy = sandy_key.get()
```

I believe this example assumes we have set a variable named sandy_key as an ndb.Key() but it doesn't really say.
I have successfully run all the ndb tutorial examples but they create a new object for each entry. I want to have only one object, call it up, edit it and put() it again. I suspect I have made the key incorrectly or called it incorrectly. I have also tried:

```
user1 = ndb.get('agxkZXZ-aWZnYWxlcnRyFwsSCkluZm9fbW9kZWwYgICAgICAgAkM')
```

Having copied the key from the admin console.  This does not work, Eclipse code editor says, "Undefined variable frome import:get". I have tried a different example from the [GAE documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/subclassprop):

```
# Create an entity and write it to the Datastore.
ent = MyModel(name='booh', xyz=[10**100, 6**666])
assert ent.abc == 0
key = ent.put()

# Read an entity back from the Datastore and update it.
ent = key.get()
ent.abc += 1
ent.xyz.append(ent.abc//3)
ent.put()
```

But this seems to be made for all being in one scope.  If I create an object in one class then try to retrieve it in another class, the variable ent in ent=key.get() is undefined.
As well I have tried many other examples in the documentation but many are incomplete and assume the reader is not a novice.
Given I have an object in the datastore, how can I retrieve that object specifically and print it out like the following:

```
class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
def get(self):
    self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
    #get object from datastore using example from GAE Documentation.
    user_key = ndb.Key('Info_model', 'Bill')
    user1 = user_key.get()
    self.response.write(user1.username)
    self.response.write(user1.phone)
    self.response.write(user1.active)
    self.response.write('</body></html>')
```

Sorry for the noob question, if there is a more appropriate forum for beginner GAE programmers please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you have created a key here ...

```
user_key = ndb.Key('Info_model', 'Bill')
```

... but this is never put() to the datastore.

Later (in your Create_entity get method) you are using ...

```
user1 = Info_model(username = 'Bill', 
                   phone = 1231231234, 
                   active = False)
user1.put()
```

... and this is correctly 'putting' the Info_model entity into the datastore.

However, this code ...

```
user_key = ndb.Key('Info_model', 'Bill')
user1 = user_key.get()
```

... attempts to get an entity of kind Info_model from the datastore with key_name "Bill", but this is not what you put into the datastore in the first place.

Maybe what you are trying to achieve, is to create an entity of kind Info_model, with key_name 'Bill', which you can then later get by keyname? If that is the case, try this code ...

```
user1 = Info_model.get_or_insert('Bill',
                                 username='Bill', 
                                 phone=1231231234, 
                                 active=False)

user2_key = ndb.Key('Info_model', 'Bill')
user2 = user2_key.get()

assert user1.key == user2.key
```

Do be aware, however, that an entities key_name is final - you cannot change this later. You may want to consider how you would handle the scenario where Bill wanted to change his username.

As a side note, I would recommend using an ndb.StringProperty for the phone property, as often phone numbers start with a 0, or contain spaces or characters such as +

Comment: This was a big help.  For other new programmers, I used the following to print this you will want more formatting but this is the important part.self.response.out.write('<html><body>')
        self.response.write(user2.username)
        self.response.write(user2.phone)
        self.response.write(user2.active)
        self.response.write('</body></html>')